# Closing tags in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I will get straight into it.
I want to code a Code Editor for HTML, CSS, and JS with Python Tkinter, but I don't know how to make an automated "closing tag system".
and I also want to know how to make each tag another color, automatically.
I'm really struggling with this because I am also new at python
Here some code:
PYTHON:

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.title('text-editor - reddrosee')
root.geometry('1200x660')
root.configure(background='white')

#SAVEFILE
def new_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)
    root.title('New File - reddrosee')

#OPEN FILE
def open_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)

    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/reddrosee/", title="Open File", filetypes=(("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    name = text_file
    root.title(name + ' - reddrosee')

    text_file = open(text_file, 'r')
    read_text = text_file.read()
    my_text.insert(END, read_text)

    text_file.close()

def save_as_file():
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", initialdir="C:/reddrosee/", title="Save File", filetypes=(("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if text_file:
        name = text_file
        name = name.replace("C:/reddrosee/", "")
        root.title(name + ' - reddrosee')

        text_file = open(text_file, 'w')
        text_file.write(my_text.get(1.0, END))
        root.title('SAVED' + ' - reddrosee')

        text_file.close()

#CREATE MAIN FRAME
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

#SCROLLBAR(TEXTBOX)
text_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

#CREATE TEXTBOX
myFont = font.Font(family='monospace')
my_text = Text(my_frame, width=1920, height=1080, font=(myFont, 16), bg="white",selectbackground="silver", fg="black" ,selectforeground="white", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)
my_text.pack()

#CONFIG SCROLLBAR
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)

#MENU
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

#FILEMENU
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=new_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As", command=save_as_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command= root.quit)

#ADD EDIT MENU
edit_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Undo")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Redo")

root.mainloop()
```

-REDDROSEEEE

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it. Create your tags in the form of a dictionary and check the last inserted character in the text widget. If the last character matches the key in the dictionary then insert the value at the end. Also bind the text widget with the function:

```
tags = {'{':'}', '[':']', '(': ')'}# add your auto complete tags here
    
    
def autoComplete(*event):
    pos = my_text.index(INSERT)
    text.set(my_text.get('1.0', END))
    inputValue = text.get()[-2:].strip()
    backspace = str(event[0])

    if 'BackSpace' not in backspace.split()[3]:
        if inputValue in list(tags.keys()):
            my_text.insert(END, tags[inputValue])
```

The complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font


tags = {'{':'}', '[':']', '(': ')'}# add your auto complete tags here


def autoComplete(*event):
    pos = my_text.index(INSERT)
    text.set(my_text.get('1.0', END))
    inputValue = text.get()[-2:].strip()
    backspace = str(event[0])

    if 'BackSpace' not in backspace.split()[3]:
        if inputValue in list(tags.keys()):
            my_text.insert(END, tags[inputValue])

            
root = Tk()
root.title('text-editor - reddrosee')
root.geometry('1200x660')
root.configure(background='white')

#SAVEFILE
def new_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)
    root.title('New File - reddrosee')

#OPEN FILE
def open_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)

    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/reddrosee/", title="Open File", filetypes=(("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    name = text_file
    root.title(name + ' - reddrosee')

    text_file = open(text_file, 'r')
    read_text = text_file.read()
    my_text.insert(END, read_text)

    text_file.close()

def save_as_file():
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", initialdir="C:/reddrosee/", title="Save File", filetypes=(("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if text_file:
        name = text_file
        name = name.replace("C:/reddrosee/", "")
        root.title(name + ' - reddrosee')

        text_file = open(text_file, 'w')
        text_file.write(my_text.get(1.0, END))
        root.title('SAVED' + ' - reddrosee')

        text_file.close()

#CREATE MAIN FRAME
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

#SCROLLBAR(TEXTBOX)
text_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text = StringVar()
#text.trace('w', autoComplete)

#CREATE TEXTBOX
myFont = font.Font(family='monospace')
my_text = Text(my_frame, width=1920, height=1080, font=(myFont, 16), bg="white",
               selectbackground="silver", fg="black" ,selectforeground="white", undo=True,
               yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)

my_text.pack()

my_text.bind('<KeyRelease>', autoComplete)

#CONFIG SCROLLBAR
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)

#MENU
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

#FILEMENU
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=new_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As", command=save_as_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command= root.quit)

#ADD EDIT MENU
edit_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Undo")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Redo")

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:** you may also use `event.keycode` instead of slicing and using `strip` in the autocomplete function. Refer to my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am adding another answer my previous answer works only for the tags at the end.
Use this, this will auto-complete the tags anywhere in the program.

Also, this is better than the previous one.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font


tags = {'{':'}', '[':']', '(':')'}# add your auto complete tags here
reject_keys = [8, 16, 17, 18, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40]

def autoComplete(event):
 
    pos = f'{float(my_text.index(INSERT))-0.1:1.1f}' 
    inputValue = my_text.get(pos).strip()
    backspace = event.keycode
 
    if backspace not in reject_keys:
        if inputValue in list(tags.keys()):
            insert_pos = my_text.index(INSERT)
            my_text.insert(insert_pos, tags[inputValue])

            
root = Tk()
root.title('text-editor - reddrosee')
root.geometry('1200x660')
root.configure(background='white')

#SAVEFILE
def new_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)
    root.title('New File - reddrosee')

#OPEN FILE
def open_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)

    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/reddrosee/", title="Open File", filetypes=(("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    name = text_file
    root.title(name + ' - reddrosee')

    text_file = open(text_file, 'r')
    read_text = text_file.read()
    my_text.insert(END, read_text)

    text_file.close()

def save_as_file():
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", initialdir="C:/reddrosee/", title="Save File", filetypes=(("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if text_file:
        name = text_file
        name = name.replace("C:/reddrosee/", "")
        root.title(name + ' - reddrosee')

        text_file = open(text_file, 'w')
        text_file.write(my_text.get(1.0, END))
        root.title('SAVED' + ' - reddrosee')

        text_file.close()

#CREATE MAIN FRAME
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

#SCROLLBAR(TEXTBOX)
text_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

text = StringVar()
#text.trace('w', autoComplete)

#CREATE TEXTBOX
myFont = font.Font(family='monospace')
my_text = Text(my_frame, width=1920, height=1080, font=(myFont, 16), bg="white",
               selectbackground="silver", fg="black" ,selectforeground="white", undo=True,
               yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)

my_text.pack()

my_text.bind('<KeyRelease>', autoComplete)

#CONFIG SCROLLBAR
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)

#MENU
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

#FILEMENU
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=new_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As", command=save_as_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command= root.quit)

#ADD EDIT MENU
edit_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Undo")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Redo")

root.mainloop()
```